# what is the value of -Infinity ? how it will work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't understand whats happening here , anybody can help me to know about this

```js
function findMax() {
    var i;
    var max = -Infinity;
    for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] > max) {
            max = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
} 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = findMax(4, 5, 6);
```

```html
<p>Finding the largest number.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: what your issue it is unclear for us

Comment: `max` is set to the lowest number([`-Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity)), which will allow to pass negative numbers to `findMax()`.

Comment: seems like a clarification required, not a problem

Comment: -Infinity is the smallest number from the universe (citation needed)

Comment: a cleaner solution will be to set max to the first element of the array `max = arguments[0]`

Comment: @madalinivascu I'm not a mathematician, but I think -infinity is only the smallest *real* number. When talking about `numbers` in general it's not exactly specific as there are quite a few number types http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/number-types.html (just to go completely off topic here)

Comment: @Robba (citation needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) does not have a value, it represents a number higher than all others. (or lower, in case of `-Infinity`)

It is usually used in functions such as finding maximum or minimum to have something to compare the first number against.

In your case, you have a function that loops a list of numbers to find the maximum. You do that by comparing each of them to the maximum number found until that, but what are you going to compare the first number with? One solution is to compare it with `-Infinity`, which is preferable to using `arguments[0]` or `null` as default, when you want the function to return a comparable value even if you call it with no arguments.

Comment: why not do `max = arguments[0]` what advantages does this have?

Comment: The advantage of using `Infinity` is that it allows you to call the function without any arguments, and it will return an object that can be used in further comparisons. This is useful when the argument list is dynamically generated.